# Using IF condition in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to join the table depending on the value of another table. In my scenario, I want to join table `job` when `message.type` is job else join with table `post_ads`. I had written below MySql query, but its throwing syntax error. Please help.

```
 SELECT message.*,register.name, rg.name as to_user_name, post_ads.*
 FROM message 
 INNER JOIN register ON message.from_user_id = register.id 
 INNER JOIN register rg ON message.to_user_id = rg.id LEFT JOIN 

 CASE message.type WHEN 'job' THEN 

 SELECT 'job.title' as titles FROM job 
 WHERE (message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
 (message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196')

  ELSE

  SELECT 'post_ads.brand_category, post_ads.model_category, post_ads.titles, 
  post_ads.images, post_ads.ads_main_pic'  FROM post_ads  
  WHERE (message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
  (message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196')

  END as post_ads
```

Comment: Please provide the error message. Also is there PHP to the question, sounds like just mysql..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have misused case statement. It should be inside select statement not in left join.
2nd, you cannot select multiple fields when we use case statement. - To over come this issue you can use CONCAT function with user defined contastant and manipulate in the server side script.

You should write query something like the below one,

```
SELECT message.*,register.name, rg.name AS to_user_name, post_ads.*,

CASE `message`.`type` WHEN 'job' THEN 

(SELECT job.title  FROM job 
WHERE (message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
(message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196')) 

ELSE

(SELECT  post_ads.titles FROM post_ads  
WHERE (message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
(message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196'))

END AS post_ads

FROM message 
INNER JOIN register ON message.from_user_id = register.id 
INNER JOIN register rg ON message.to_user_id = rg.id
```

Comment: thank you for the time and is it possible to use job.* instead if I cannot select multiple fields?

Comment: No, You cannot use * inside case statement. You can use CONCAT or equivalent function since it will return a single filed value.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
$query = ("select * from `table1` where (`param`='$param' AND `$param2 `='$param2') OR `param3`='$param3");
```

modify it to fit your query.

EDIT

went again trough your code and I think that you miss brackets:

```js
 SELECT message.*,register.name, rg.name as to_user_name, post_ads.*
 FROM message 
 INNER JOIN register ON message.from_user_id = register.id 
 INNER JOIN register rg ON message.to_user_id = rg.id LEFT JOIN 

 CASE message.type WHEN 'job' THEN 

 SELECT 'job.title' as titles FROM job 
 WHERE ((message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
 (message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196'))

  ELSE

  SELECT 'post_ads.brand_category, post_ads.model_category, post_ads.titles, 
  post_ads.images, post_ads.ads_main_pic'  FROM post_ads  
  WHERE( (message.`from_user_id` = '196' AND message.`to_user_id` = '218') OR 
  (message.`from_user_id` = '218' AND message.`to_user_id` = '196'))

  END as post_ads
```

Comment: Please format your answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks